# Structure of desktop application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, desktop-application

Please have look at the attached image i have created. I have done this diagram on my own by the information got from the internet. The diagram tells out stucture of multithreaded desktop application in C# .NET. if any one can suggest any changes that would be really gratful. I have to give a presentation on this topic tommorow :) also if you know any related documets about this topic with some diagramatic representation, that would be really helpful for me.

Looking forward to get some reply soon.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me, but because the workerthread appears isolated, It looks quite circular.

Comment: The worker thread is not different entity. I mean to say worker thread is resopsible for the executing tasks (not the UI thread). Execute long task is done by worker thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. please provide me if you have any documents that can be supportive for this diagram.